# Constructing the largest finite group with a fixed number of conjugacy classes

Tags: gr.group-theory, conjugacy-classes

It is known that there are finitely many finite groups with a given number of conjugacy classes.  How can one construct (or get a character table for) the groups $G$ that realize the maximum possible order among groups with $k$ conjugacy classes?  Help even with $k=4$ or 5 would be very useful.

Comment: In a first step you can ask about estimates on the order of such a group (possibly with $\le k$ conjugacy classes rather than exactly $k$), and ask about groups with $\le k$ conjugacy classes of cardinal "asymptotically" maximal.

Comment: I didn't know the first statement of your question.  Do you know a reference?

Comment: I know it is due to Landau, but I don't have an exact reference.

Comment: E.Landau proved in around 1895 that for a fixed $k$, there are only finitely many solutions to $\sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n_{j}} = 1$ in positive integers. Apply this to the class equation of a finite group.

Comment: The groups are known up to $k=14$ at least, see Vera-López, A., Sangroniz, Josu, The finite groups with thirteen and fourteen conjugacy classes. Math. Nachr. 280 (2007), no. 5-6, 676–694.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58794/bounds-on-number-of-conjugacy-classes-in-terms-of-number-of-elements-of-a-group and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46981/are-some-numbers-more-likely-to-count-conjugacy-classes-than-others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following @verret comment, here are the list of the largest finite groups $G_k$ with a fixed class number $k\le 14$ (i.e. the number of conjugacy classes of elements, or the number of irreducible complex representations up to equiv.), coming from the papers of Vera-López and Sangroniz [MR804489](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=804489), [MR880291](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=880291), [MR2308490](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2308490).
See also [OEIS/A002319](https://oeis.org/A002319). We will consider $c_k:=|G_k|^{1/k}$.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
k & G_k & |G_k| &  c_k \newline 
\hline                           
1 & C_1 & 1 & 1  \newline 
\hline 
2 & C_2 & 2 & 1.4142\dots \newline 
\hline 
3 & S_3 & 6 & 1.8171\dots \newline 
\hline 
4 & A_4 & 12 & 1.8612\dots \newline 
\hline 
5 & A_5 & 60 & 2.2679\dots \newline 
\hline 
6 & PSL(2,7) & 168 & 2.3490\dots \newline 
\hline 
7 & A_6 & 360 & 2.3183\dots \newline 
\hline 
8 & M_{10} & 720 & 2.2759\dots \newline 
\hline 
9 & A_7 & 2520 & 2.3874\dots \newline 
\hline 
10 & PSL(3,4) & 20160 & 2.6943\dots \newline 
\hline 
11 & Sz(8) & 29120 & 2.5458\dots \newline 
\hline 
12 & M_{22} & 443520  & 2.9551\dots \newline 
\hline 
13 & C_9^2:SL(2,3)  & 1944  & 1.7905\dots \newline 
\hline 
14 & PSU(3,5) & 126000 & 2.3137\dots \newline 
\end{array}$

*Monstrous question*: Is it true that $G_{194} = M$?
If so, $c_{194} = 1.8960\dots$

**Bertram's problem** ([19.11](https://kourovkanotebookorg.files.wordpress.com/2018/12/19tkt-1.pdf); [B](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2258655)): Is there $\alpha$ such that for any finite group $G$ of class number $k(G)$ then $$|G| \le \alpha^{k(G)}$$

*Bonus question 1*:  Is $c_k \le c_{12}$ for all $k$?

If so, it would solve Bertram's problem explicitly with $\alpha = c_{12}$.
In particular, we would have $|G|< 3^{k(G)}$ for any $G$ (checked by GAP for $G$ simple with $|G|<10^7$).

*Bonus question 2*: Is it true that $c_k \to 1$ when $k \to \infty$?

If so, it would solve Bertram's problem implicitly.
I guess it is known (from CFSG) that for $G$ simple, $|G|^{1/k(G)} \to 1$ when $|G| \to \infty$. We can reduce to the infinite families, ok for $C_p$ and $A_n$, now if $X(q)$ is a generic finite simple group of Lie type then $\exists n,m \ge 1$ such that $|X(q)| = O(q^n)$ and $k(X(q)) = O(q^m)$, but $q^{n/{q^m}} \to 1$ when $q \to \infty$.
Then, an eventual reduction of Bertram's problem to the simple group case should solve it.